# finding the route between 2 nodes in a directed graph?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

I am struggling with following piece of code, as I try to write a function for finding if there is route between two nodes:

the main where I can `isThereRoute` function.

```
ArrayList<Node> visited = new ArrayList();
visted.add(start_node);
System.out.println(isThereRoute(start_node, end_node, visited));
```

the following is function

```
bool isThereRoute(Node A, Node B, ArrayList<Node> visited){
    flag = false;
    if(A == B) return true;
    for(Node n : A.adjacent()){
        if (!visited.contains(n)) {
            visited.add(n);
            flag = isThereRoute(n, B, visited);
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

All the nodes are in Graph class where Adjacent() returns a adjacency list. The program sometimes works but in most cases print false even there is a route between 2 nodes.

Comment: The accepted answer on this page may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39071077/finding-path-between-2-points-in-racket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break the loop if there is a route, or when flag is true.

```
bool isThereRoute(Node A, Node B, ArrayList<Node> visited){
    flag = false;
    if(A == B) return true;
    for(Node n : A.adjacent()){
        if (!visited.contains(n)) {
            visited.add(n);
            flag = isThereRoute(n, B, visited);
        }
        if (flag == true) break;  //<====insert here
    }
    return flag;
}
```

if you don't break the loop, flag may be changed to false on any subsequent iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Your line `flag = isThereRoute(n, B)` will mean that the flag is set to the last node checked. That makes no sense - it should stop as soon as it finds a path:

```
if (A == B)
    return true;
for (Node n: n.adjacent()) {
    if (!visited.contains(n)) {
        visited.add(n);
        if (isThereRoute(n, B, visited))
            return true;
    }
}
return false;
```