# Find path between 2 points from given connections

Tags: prolog, ocaml

I want to solve a typical Prolog problem from [here](http://www.cs.ccsu.edu/~markov/ccsu_courses/prolog.txt) in Ocaml

Connections are represented by following data:

```
arc(1,2).
arc(2,3).
arc(3,4).
arc(3,5).
arc(2,5).
arc(5,6).
arc(2,6).
```

One has to find a path given start and end points (solution to be stored in P), e.g.:

```
?- path(1,6,P).
```

Prolog code for this is as follows:

```
path(X,Y,[arc(X,Y)]) :- arc(X,Y).
path(X,Y,[arc(X,Z)|P]) :- arc(X,Z),path(Z,Y,P).
```

Output will be as:

```
P = [arc(1, 2), arc(2, 6)] .
```

I see that that there are many pattern matching capabilities in Ocaml. How can above problem be solved in Ocaml?

Edit: I am not insisting on unification method.

Comment: Good observations. If you post these together as an answer, there will be many upvotes.

Comment: Pl see my edit.

Comment: Where are all your comments? Seriously, have you deleted them? Pl add them back.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that unification method as used in prolog code above cannot be applied from Ocaml?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39071077/finding-path-between-2-points-in-racket

Comment: Any language other than prolog or its derivatives where this is built-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCaml is not a logic programming language. It is a conventional multi-paradigm, functional, imperative, and object-oriented language. So there are no builtin constructs for solving logical problems (beyond type checking) or anything like this.

However, your problem is a typical graph problem, so you can use any graph library available in OCaml, to solve it, here is the solution implemented using [Graphlib](http://binaryanalysisplatform.github.io/bap/api/odoc/graphlib/Graphlib/Std/index.html)'s [shortest path](http://binaryanalysisplatform.github.io/bap/api/odoc/graphlib/Graphlib/Std/Graphlib/index.html#val-shortest_path) algorithm, which implements the classical [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

```
open Core_kernel
open Graphlib.Std

module G = Graphlib.Make(Int)(Unit)

let graph = Graphlib.create (module G) () ~edges:[
          1,2,();
          2,3,();
          3,4,();
          3,5,();
          2,5,();
          5,6,();
          2,6,();
]

let () = 
  match Graphlib.shortest_path (module G) graph 1 6 with
  | None -> printf "No path\n"
  | Some p -> 
    Path.edges p |> Sequence.iter ~f:(fun e ->
      printf "Arc(%d, %d)\n" (G.Edge.src e) (G.Edge.dst e))
```

You can install graphlib using opam

```
  opam install graphlib
```

then, if you put your program in a separate folder and name, let's say, `check_path.ml`, you can built and run it using `ocamlbuild`, e.g.

```
 $ ocamlbuild -package graphlib check_path.native --
 Arc(1, 2)
 Arc(2, 6)
```